# R - multiply dataframe by vectors with different sizes, tidyverse/pipe style

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following code:

```
dfl <- group_split(mtcars, am)

v <- list()

v[[1]] <- seq(1:6)

v[[2]] <- seq(1:8)

x <- list()

for(i in 1:2){
  x[[i]] <- list()
for (j in 1:length(v[[i]])){
  x[[i]][[j]] <- dfl[[i]]$qsec*v[[i]][[j]]
}
}

x[[1]] <- reduce(x[[1]], bind_cols)
x[[2]] <- reduce(x[[2]], bind_cols)
```

I wish to achieve this same output, but in tidyverse style and all within a single pipeline without breaking the pipe. This has proved to be more difficult because vectors `v[[1]]` and `v[[2]]` are of different length. I tried using the map2 function, but it fails for this precise reason. What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to return - it looks like you just want multiples of the qsec column.. You can do that like this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_split(am) %>%
  map2(.x=.,.y=list(1:6,1:8),~as.data.frame(sapply(.y, \(y) .x$qsec*y)))
```

Output (same as your `x[[1]] and x[[2]]`)

```
[[1]]
      V1    V2    V3    V4     V5     V6
1  19.44 38.88 58.32 77.76  97.20 116.64
2  17.02 34.04 51.06 68.08  85.10 102.12
3  20.22 40.44 60.66 80.88 101.10 121.32
4  15.84 31.68 47.52 63.36  79.20  95.04
5  20.00 40.00 60.00 80.00 100.00 120.00
6  22.90 45.80 68.70 91.60 114.50 137.40
7  18.30 36.60 54.90 73.20  91.50 109.80
8  18.90 37.80 56.70 75.60  94.50 113.40
9  17.40 34.80 52.20 69.60  87.00 104.40
10 17.60 35.20 52.80 70.40  88.00 105.60
11 18.00 36.00 54.00 72.00  90.00 108.00
12 17.98 35.96 53.94 71.92  89.90 107.88
13 17.82 35.64 53.46 71.28  89.10 106.92
14 17.42 34.84 52.26 69.68  87.10 104.52
15 20.01 40.02 60.03 80.04 100.05 120.06
16 16.87 33.74 50.61 67.48  84.35 101.22
17 17.30 34.60 51.90 69.20  86.50 103.80
18 15.41 30.82 46.23 61.64  77.05  92.46
19 17.05 34.10 51.15 68.20  85.25 102.30

[[2]]
      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5     V6     V7     V8
1  16.46 32.92 49.38 65.84 82.30  98.76 115.22 131.68
2  17.02 34.04 51.06 68.08 85.10 102.12 119.14 136.16
3  18.61 37.22 55.83 74.44 93.05 111.66 130.27 148.88
4  19.47 38.94 58.41 77.88 97.35 116.82 136.29 155.76
5  18.52 37.04 55.56 74.08 92.60 111.12 129.64 148.16
6  19.90 39.80 59.70 79.60 99.50 119.40 139.30 159.20
7  18.90 37.80 56.70 75.60 94.50 113.40 132.30 151.20
8  16.70 33.40 50.10 66.80 83.50 100.20 116.90 133.60
9  16.90 33.80 50.70 67.60 84.50 101.40 118.30 135.20
10 14.50 29.00 43.50 58.00 72.50  87.00 101.50 116.00
11 15.50 31.00 46.50 62.00 77.50  93.00 108.50 124.00
12 14.60 29.20 43.80 58.40 73.00  87.60 102.20 116.80
13 18.60 37.20 55.80 74.40 93.00 111.60 130.20 148.80
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am looking to multiply each row in qsec first by 1, then by 2, then by 3... and so until 6, and in the other dataframe until 8. 

I cannot accept your answer although it produces the same output because it requires the list of vectors v to be defined before your code is executed. I would like to have everything in the same pipeline, so starting with mtcars %>% group_split(am) %>% and then continuing onwards

Comment: but why not just define them in .y? (see edit)

Comment: @J.Doe obsessing over having everything in the same pipeline is often misguided. You should aim for clear, readable, efficient code. Does cramming that info into the pipeline provide any true advantage outside of simply being in the pipeline? I don't see a logic rule that comes up with the 6 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `outer`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_split(am) %>% 
  map2(list(6, 8), ~ as.data.frame(outer(.x$qsec, seq.int(.y))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A direct interpretation would be

```r
v <- list()
v[[1]] <- seq(1:6)
v[[2]] <- seq(1:8)
names(v) <- levels(factor(mtcars$am))
v["0"]

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am) %>% 
  group_map(function(value, key) {
    t(tcrossprod(
      v[[as.character(key)]],
      value$qsec
    ))
  }) %>% 
  identity()
```

Now, a few thing: `am` is a numeric, so to index it, we used `names` property.
Hence why the `key` has to be converted with `as.character`.
Also, note that `identity` does nothing, but it is a way to end pipes, so as to be able to comment-out parts without having to remove the leading `%>%`.